# How do I ask for "at least" a size of an int in C

Tags: c++, c, optimization

The situation:

I have an application written in C which is resource intensive, and designed to be portable. I want to allow the compiler to select the fastest int size for the architecture, provided it is at least 32 bits.

Is it possible to select a size of "at least" 32 bits, or will the compiler optimize these kinds of things form me automatically?

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Is C++ compatibility required?

Comment: I think it's what `long` is for.

Comment: You are looking for `stdint.h` typedefs, like `int_least32_t`

Comment: @Quentin: No it isn't.

Comment: @Kaiserludi Yes it is. `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits wide.

Comment: @Quentin: And where does the standard guarantee, that long is always the fastest integer type of an architecture?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Sorry, I meant to address you, of course.

Comment: @Kaiserludi that "think" was genuine. The standard allows room for the integer types sizes, and AFAIK implementations use this to suit the CPU's architecture (and thus gain speed). But indeed nothing forces them to.

Comment: @Kaiserludi: That's called Quality of Implementation. As far as the Standard is concerned, there could be a `_FasterThanLongButOtherwiseIdentical` type, and there's no way to discover that. But in the real world, `long` is the fastest type with at least 32 bits.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The standard header `stdint.h` provides the types `int_leastN_t` and `uint_leastN_t`, where `N` is 8, 16, 32, and 64 (and possibly others, but these are not required). These are standard as of C99.

It also provides "fast" alternatives, aka `int_fastN_t` and `uint_fastN_t`, with the same values of `N`.

So, in your case, you can use `int_least32_t` or `int_fast32_t`.

Comment: `int_fast32_t` is what the OP needs here. `int_least32_t` is not the fastest integer type with 32+ bits, just the smallest.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Except that `int_fast32_t` is misdefined on important archs like x86_64 where it's actually a **much slower** type (64-bit instead of 32-bit): for `+`/`-`/`*` both are identical speed, but for `/` it's much slower, and of course loads/stores are slower since you use twice as many cache lines and twice as much memory bandwidth. So I'd be really hesitant to use it. I'm not aware of **any** arch that has a 32-bit int where it's not the fastest type for working with "at least 32-bit" integers.

Comment: @R..: Shouldn't the same thing hold true for `short`? i.e. shouldn't division of shorts be faster (assuming they are actually smaller and C didn't automatically promote them to `int`)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Probably, but often there *is* an added cost to loading/storing and performing operations on shorts. On some old x86's the operand size prefix prevented pipelining; perhaps now the only cost is increased instruction cache usage. Of course this is another reason the "fast" types are misguided -- which type is faster may very well depend on the specific cpu model, not just the ISA. And you can't practically have the type change depending on `-march` or something because that would break ABI.

Comment: @R..: Thanks for the extra info, feels like it deserves to be an answer on it's own. It seems like as always there are many levels of complexity if you really want to optimize. You're also hinting at the fact you have to involve cache management, possibly including asm, to get good optimization, and that would make a bigger difference than type width?

Answer (score 20):

As others have noted, the standard include files define `int_fast32_t`, `int_least32_t`, `uint_fast32_t`, `uint_least32_t`  which should likely behave as you want, but such types need to be used with extreme care.  Because of integer promotion rules, there is no way for C code to avoid using types `int` and `unsigned int`.  Further, integer literals may not always be of the types one expects.  A comparison between an `int_fast32_T` and the literals `0xABCD1234` or `12345u`, for example, may be performed as either signed or unsigned, depending upon whether `int` is 16, 32, or 64 bits.  Likewise, if `n` is 32 bits or larger, the meaning of `n &= ~0x8000;` would be different on a 16-bit machine from on a larger one.

The C standard was never particularly designed to facilitate writing code which cares about integer sizes, but will nonetheless work compatibly on hardware with different sizes.  Types like `int_fast32_t` make it easy to write code which seems like it should be portable, but may encourage complacency with respect to all of the nasty little traps hidden in the language.

Answer (score 10):

This question was tagged as C++ too, so here is a solution for template metaprogramming lovers like me.

#### Requirements

- A typelist type, named `list` here.
- A Haskell-like `filter` metafunction.
- A `head` metafunction to get the first element of a typelist.

#### The code

This solution automates the accepted solution (Which is just *"go to `stdint.h` and select the most apropiate for you"*). That job could be done by the compiler, couldn't it?

First list all the platform specific fastest integer types declared at `<cstdint>`:

```
using integer_types = list<std::int_fast8_t,std::int_fast16_t,
                           std::int_fast32_t,std::int_fast64_t>;
```

Note the list is sorted by increasing integer size.
Now define a filtering predicate. In our case, the size should be less than the size specified by the user (name it `SIZE`):

```
template<typename T>
using f = std::integral_constant<bool,sizeof(T)*CHAR_BITS <= SIZE>;
```

And then filter the list of integer types and get the first element of the result:

```
using best_integer_t = head<filter<f,integer_types>>;
```

#### Summarized solution

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
struct fastest_integer_impl
{
    //Guard for the case the user specified less than one byte size:
    static constexpr const std::size_t size = SIZE >= CHAR_BITS ? size : CHAR_BITS;

    using integer_types = list<std::int_fast8_t,std::int_fast16_t,
                               std::int_fast32_t,std::int_fast64_t>;

    template<typename T>
    using f = std::integral_constant<bool,sizeof(T)*CHAR_BITS <= size>;

    using type = head<filter<f,integer_types>>;
};

template<std::size_t SIZE>
using fastest_integer = typename fastest_integer_impl<SIZE>::type;
```

Comment: Won't `fastest_integer<4>` give the same as `std::int_fast32_t`? How is this any better than just directly using `std::int_fast32_t`?

Comment: @PeterSW sorry, was a typo on the implementation. The metafunction was supposed to work with size in bits. The point of the metafunction is to automatize the integer selection process. Something like *"I'm working with 20 bits, whats the fastest integer type you have with at least that size?"*

Answer (score -5):

fastest => align to architecture using pragma pack. Without this, in case the memory is not aligned, it would require more than one memory access.

min 32 => use int specifier - enough. This ensures 32 bits in linux across all architectures to my knowledge.

Comment: Actually quite the opposite. `pragma pack` will *cause* misalignment because it prevents the compiler from inserting the padding needed to keep the data aligned.

Comment: He said "portable"; can't assume linux. 16 bit systems are admittedly rare nowadays, but I don't think you can rule them out unless the question actually says so.

Comment: Don't know how had I posted such an answer. I think, I must have posted this answer for a wrong question by mistake.